# PHP Include throwing include_path error

Tags: php

I'm trying to use some include statements on my website and having some issues:

Here's the error:

> Failed opening '../connection.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.;C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox\www') in
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox\www\network\core\user\UserAccount.php
>   on line 6

Original include_path was looking in the xamp PEAR directory, i tried changing this using

```
    set_include_path('.;C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox\www');
```

My server is configured to run straight off of my dropbox.

Comment: dunno, if you can include from your c:/, there is a blindshot to suggest you to change `c:\ .... \www` to `localhost`

Comment: Yes @Pepo_rasta may be correct. try doing that.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, and I got the .;c;\ from the docs